# Elastic Search bucket list for a ECommerce Shop / Neast Attributes

Tags: php, elasticsearch

can you help me please? I have a ecommerce website with 1000+ products. Each product has a bunch of options like "color", "size", and other specs... but i don't know all the attributes. so i define a document with this mapping:

```
"mappings" : { 
   "article" : { 
      "properties": { 
           "options":     {    
                 "type": "nested",
                 "include_in_parent":"true",
                 "properties": {
                      "id": {"type": "string"}, 
                      "name": {"type": "string"},
                       "values": {"type": "string"}
                  }
            }
      }
}
```

And this is my Query to get the Bucket list:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "categorie_id": "f52330ce2669dfab884c2d60468b8466"
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": [],
      "should": []
    }
  },
  "from": 0,
  "size": 1,
  "sort": [
    {
      "sorttype": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    },
    "_score"
  ],
  "aggs": {
    "baked_goods": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "options"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "name": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "id"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "name": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "values"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I get Documents, but the Result of the Buckets is Empty...

```
"aggregations": {
  "baked_goods": {
    "doc_count": 3331,
    "name": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [ ]
    }
  }
}
```

i want something like:

```
"color" => "red" (4)
"color" => "blue" (2)
"size" => "X" (11)
```

..

Can you please help me??

Answer (score 0):

i found a solution.

Mapping:

```
"options":     {    
                                "type": "nested",
                                "include_in_parent": true,
                                "properties": {
                                    "name": { "type": "text"  , "analyzer": "whitespace", "fielddata": true},
                                    "values": { "type": "text"  , "analyzer": "whitespace", "fielddata": true}
                                }
                            }
```

Query:

```
"aggs": {
                                "facets": {
                                  "nested": {
                                    "path": "options"
                                  },
                                  "aggs": {
                                    "name": {
                                      "terms": {
                                        "field": "options.name"
                                      },
                                      "aggs": {
                                        "name": {
                                          "terms": {
                                            "field": "options.values"
                                          }
                                        }
                                      }
                                    }
                                  }
                                } }
```